# Getting substring of a string from different aspects

Tags: php

I need to get substring from a string where it will give output of first 25 characters from different aspects. Here substring should only consider commas (,) not spaces.

*Scenario 1:*

```
$str = "the, quick, brown, fox";

$res = "the, quick, brown, fox";
```

*Scenario 2:*

```
$str = "the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over, the, lazy, dog!";

$res = "the, quick, brown, fox, more";
```

*Scenario 3:*

```
$str = "the quick, brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog!";

$res = "the quick, brown fox, more";
```

*Scenario 4:*

```
$str = "the quick brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog!";

$res = "the quick brown fox, more";
```

Please help! Thanks.

*Extremely sorry for my English!*

Comment: Here in Scenario 2 , 3 ,4 what is mean from more..and i think you want result of substring in which first 25 characters (exclude space). Please reply

Comment: here its kind of like heading of a full news where it will truncate string into 25 characters string and replace with 'more' if its bigger than 25 characters. It will only search for ',' till 25 characters. Look at scenario 4 where it is suppose to show "the quick brown, fox jump" , but since there's no ',' at the end it will get substring upto previous ',' and return "the quick brown fox, more"

Comment: and i dono whoever this is, thanks for your negative reputation. Here we are suppose to help people and of-course we have the power of negative reputation but only with some valid cause. Please explain your reason first and than go for negative feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 4 Scenarios tested

(assuming that a comma is within the first 25 characters )

```
function stringm($string, $length = 25){

   if(strlen($string) >= $length){
       $string = substr($string, 0, $length-1);
        $str_array = explode(",", $string);
        // add logics here to check array len if comma may not be within the first 25 characters 
        array_pop($str_array);
        $string = implode(",", $str_array)  . ', more';
   }

   return $string;
}


echo stringm('the, quick, brown, fox')  . '<br>';
echo stringm('the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over, the, lazy, dog!')  . '<br>';
echo stringm('the quick, brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog!')  . '<br>';
echo stringm('the quick brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog!')  . '<br>';
```

the, quick, brown, fox

the, quick, brown, fox, more

the quick, brown fox, more

the quick brown fox, more

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but try changing the value 15 instead of 25. Its not giving the correct output. And what if the 25th character is a comma? It should add 'more' instead of ', more' so that there's no double commas.

Comment: Try my new code now.. if it doesn't work provide me with as test case

Comment: Good Job! both my code and your code return same answer. Thanks bro for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just figured out a solution. I am not sure about the feasibility, but it works great for me.

*Method:*

```
function excerpt($string, $length = 25) {
$new_string = $string;

if(strlen($string) >= $length) {
    $new_string = "";
    $array = explode(',', $string);
    $current = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $current+= strlen($array[$i])+1;
        if($current <= $length)
            $new_string.= $array[$i].",";
        else {
            $new_string.= " more";
            $i = count($array);
        }
    }       
}
return $new_string;
```

}

*Input:*

```
echo excerpt('the, quick, brown, fox').'<br>';
echo excerpt('the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over, the, lazy, dog!').'<br>';
echo excerpt('the quick, brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog!').'<br>';
echo excerpt('the quick brown, fox jumps over, the lazy dog!').'<br>';
echo excerpt('the quick brown fox, jum, ps, over, the lazy dog!').'<br>';
```

*Output:*

```
the, quick, brown, fox
the, quick, brown, fox, more
the quick, brown fox, more
the quick brown, more
the quick brown fox, jum, more
```

This code has only been tested by me. If there's any error or exception, please feedback. Thanks.